# Strong Parameters for Nested has_one Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I seem to be missing something obvious, but I am unable to permit the attributes for a nested `has_one` association.

#### Controller:

```
def create
  @crossword = Crossword.new(crossword_params)

  if @crossword.save
    render :show, status: :created, location: [:api, @crossword]
  else
    render json: @crossword.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity 
  end
end

def crossword_params
  params.require(:crossword).permit(:title, :grid_size, grid_size_attributes: [:rows, :columns])
end
```

#### Model:

```
validates :title, :grid_size, presence: true
validates_associated :grid_size
has_one :grid_size
accepts_nested_attributes_for :grid_size
```

#### Request:

```
POST /api/crosswords.json HTTP/1.1
X-Accept: application/crosswords.v1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/2.1 (Macintosh; OS X/10.10.0) GCDHTTPRequest
Content-Length: 83

{"crossword":{"title":"My Aweosme Crossword","grid_size":{"rows":15,"columns":15}}}
```

#### Rails Console Output:

```
Started POST "/api/crosswords.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-19 11:05:13 -0500
Processing by Api::V1::CrosswordsController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"crossword"=>{"title"=>"My Aweosme Crossword", "grid_size"=>{"rows"=>15, "columns"=>15}}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Unpermitted parameters: grid_size
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 2ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Am I missing something trivial? This seems to be how everyone is saying to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change "grid_size" to "grid_size_attributes" in your POST body.

If you want to continue to use "grid_size", update your `crossword_params` method:

```
def crossword_params
    params[:crossword][:grid_size_attributes] = params[:crossword][:grid_size] if params[:crossword][:grid_size]
    # NOTE :grid_size removed!
    params.require(:crossword).permit(:title, grid_size_attributes: [:rows, :columns])
end
```

Comment: beat me to it... most probably the OP did not use `fields_for`, which generates the correct param key

Comment: is there any way that I can allow grid_size instead? Requiring the client to send [model]_attributes seems wrong. EDIT: I am using rails for a JSON API only, no forms.

Comment: @eliot the [model]_attributes is an attribute appended to the parent model when you declare `accepts_nested_attributes_for` so it is necessary.  However, you can do a simple 1 line "hack" to achieve your results.  See Edit.

Comment: @tagCincy Awesome, thanks! (P.S. I'm also in cincinnati!, what are the odds?)

Comment: @eliot actually pretty high as this is becoming a hotbed for Rails development